# Amazon Lambda function return wrong response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS S3, API Gateway and Lambda function to resize my images on the fly. I keep having this error when the image doesn't exist:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()`

It should return a 404 instead. Here the code in the lambda function:

```
S3.headObject({Bucket: BUCKET, Key: parameters.orignalImagePath}, function(err,data) {
        if(err) {   
            console.log("[404] Image Not Found:  " + parameters.orignalImagePath);       
            return callback(null, {
                statusCode: '404',
                body: '{ "message":"Image not found." }',
            })
        }
    });
```

Here the logs from CloudWatch:

```
    START         
    {"errorMessage":"The specified key does not exist.","errorType":"NoSuchKey"....}    
    [404] Image Not Found: Folder/image.png   
    END
```

Why i'm getting a 502 when my code return a 404. I checked the ApiGateway settings but couldn't find anything.

Comment: please check : https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4119

Comment: cheers @IftekharDani I had a look at it but it doesn't say why sometimes, I get my custom statusCode and sometimes 502

Answer (score 0):

I found this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/

It might be because of the malformed response. I'm going to try with the updated response and the four fields.

```
{
    "isBase64Encoded": true|false,
    "statusCode": httpStatusCode,
    "headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
    "body": "..."
}
```

**UPDATE**: It definitely helps to change the response with those 4 fields. However, the same request gets sometimes a 404 and sometimes a 502.